# Override package from MSI installation with PIP package

Tags: windows, azure, installation, pip, windows-installer

I owned a Windows laptop that do not have any ADMIN permissions. Our firm has installed the old version of Microsoft Azure CLI with admin permission(MSI installer). But now, the Microsoft Azure CLI is outdated so I try to use a new version by installing a new version with PIP install.

```
pip install azure-cli
```

The installation worked well, but once I used the command line (az) or Terraform. Terraform still use the old version of Azure CLI.

Does anyone have a solution to override the az command from the PIP installation instead of Microsoft Azure(MSI installer)?

Limitation: Hard to deal with the IT admin of my firm to elevate the admin permissions. I would fix it by myself before asking for help from them.

Thank you.

Does anyone have a solution to override the az command from the PIP installation instead of Microsoft Azure(MSI installer)?

Answer (score 2):

To override the az command from the PIP installation and use it instead of the Microsoft Azure MSI installer, you need to ensure that the PIP-installed az executable takes precedence in your system’s PATH.

Here’s a step-by-step guide to achieve this:

**Steps:**

- Verify the PIP installation:
  Make sure you have installed the Azure CLI using PIP. If you haven’t installed it yet, you can do so using the following command:

`pip install azure-cli`

[image]

***After Successful Installation:***

[image]

- Check the location of the `PIP-installed` az executable: Find the location where the PIP-installed az command is located.
- The location depends on your Python installation and may vary between systems. Common locations are `/usr/local/bin` on `Linux/macOS` and `C:\PythonXX\Scripts` on Windows.

[image]

- Replace `/path/to/pip/az` with the actual path to the PIP-installed az executable.
- Modify your system’s PATH environment variable:
  you can set the PATH variable through the System Properties:
- Press `Win + Pause/Break` to open the System window.
- Click on “Advanced system settings.”
- Click the “Environment Variables” button.
- In the “System Variables” section, select the “Path” variable, and click “Edit.”
- Add a new entry with the path to the PIP-installed az directory, e.g., C:\path\to\pip\az.
  Click “OK” to save the changes.

[image]

- Restart or open a new terminal: After modifying the PATH variable, close and reopen your terminal or command prompt to ensure the changes take effect.
- Now, when you run the az command, the PIP-installed version should take precedence, and you’ll be using the version you installed through PIP instead of the MSI-installed one.

[image]